# URL based access for VPC instances

Tags: url, amazon-web-services, dns, acl

I have to restrict access to particular URL for an instance which is in VPC. In Security group, we are able to restrict Inbound/Outbound access only through IP address but not based on URL. How to create URL based ACLs in AWS?

Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: If the particular URL happens to be in S3, there's a built-in solution; otherwise, the security groups and network ACLs of VPC do not operate at layer 7 and can't filter by URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS VPC Restrict outbound access to certain URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815989/aws-vpc-restrict-outbound-access-to-certain-url)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any AWS service with this capability. You will need to configure this on the actual web server. Something like an Nginx reverse proxy with allow/deny rules.